# Do QGIS Field Calculator xat(n) and yat(n) functions work in version 1.7.x?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I'm trying to use the xat(n) and yat(n) in the Field Calculator but can't get them to work.
Does anybody have an example how to use them?
I need the start and end coordinates for line segments, does anybody know how to get those?

In the below list the xat() and yat() functions are listed.
http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/17/List_of_Field_Calculator_Functions

Comment: Did you use xat(0) and xat(-1)?

Comment: I have the same problem like Jonas in Qgis 1.7.3. Do somebody already now how to solve it?
thanks for any adivce

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to create a new field for each x/y point, and use the correct index number to return the position along the line. Index 0 is the starting point, and (as far as I can tell) any negative number would return the last point.

`xat(0)` in the 'expression' box, no '=' sign beforehand, will fill the new field with the x coordinate of the first point along the line, `yat(0)` likewise for the y coordinate. Use `xat(-1)` for the last point along the line.

Using a consistent terminology for your columns is a good idea - x_start / y_start, for example.

Comment: When trying the above I get the Syntax Error with: 
"Invalid expression syntax. The error message of the parser is: 'syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting $end'"
I'm trying with a normal ESRI Shapefile type Line.

Comment: @Jonas - you're right - it worked for me then I realised I'm using 1.9; trying it with 1.7.4 gave me the same error (on OSX 10.7)! Does anyone know if xat(n) is somehow available in 1.7.x?